# retrieve a computed property in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I use Vue-Dragula to drap and drop. When I drop, it triggers the method:

```
mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        Vue.vueDragula.eventBus.$on(
            'drop',
            function (args) {
                console.log(this.championship);
            }
        );

}
```

Now `this.championship` is a computed property:

```
computed: {
    championship(){
        return this.championships.find((elem) => elem.championship == this.championship_id);
    },
}
```

where `championships` and `championship_id` are global datas.

and `console.log(this.championship);` returns `undefined`

Now, I simplify, and I write:

```
computed: {
    championship(){
        return 2;
    },
}
```

and `console.log(this.championship);` keep returning `undefined`

What is wrong with my code???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vue.js/9350/using-this-in-vue#t=201703161717163376213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` isn't referring to the Vue instance anymore in the drop event function. Try setting a reference to `this` in the `mounted` function before the `$nextTick` call:

```
mounted: function () {
  let vm = this;
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    Vue.vueDragula.eventBus.$on(
      'drop',
      function (args) {
        console.log(vm.championship);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use arrow functions so your `this` will be the actual Vue instance:

```
mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        Vue.vueDragula.eventBus.$on(
            'drop',
            args => console.log(this.championship)
        );
    })
}
```